# Get Branching Model in bitbucket server via REST

Tags: rest, server, bitbucket

Someone knows how I can GET the PROJECT's branching model via REST API. Not the repository. I can not find how to do it anywhere.

In bitbucket server I find it via web at https://mybitbucket.com/plugins/servlet/branchmodel/projects/{project-key}

Answer (score 2):

I found it:

Is not in the actual version of REST API Documentation
(https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.14.0/bitbucket-rest.html)

Then, you can do GET request to:

https://mybitbucket.com/rest/branch-utils/1.0/projects/{project-key}/branchmodel/configuration

Comment: Via this, shall we enable automatic merging option too?